# Hosting net.tcp wcf service in iis7

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have created a class library project to create WCF service for net.tcp binding, which contains datacontract, service contract and service implementation class, I have also added web.config file and a .svc file. After this i went ti iis7 to create an application under default website. I added binding to support net.tcp. But site is not showing option to browse with net.tcp binding. See below pic.
[image]

I have checked WCF Non-HTTP Activation.

[image]

Services related to net.tcp are also running.
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But site is not showing option to browse with net.tcp binding

It is not showing up because net.tcp binding cannot be consumed from a web browser. However, this doesn't mean that you cannot consume it from a client application.

Comment: Thanks Botond Botos